# Expand width of absolutely positioned element to contain horizontally placed children irrespective of parent's width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm creating an image slider. I have a parent `<div>` that will mask a wider child:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="strip">
       <div class="item">
         <img src="1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="2.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="3.png">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My parent has a fixed width, and will show scrollbars when content overflows:

```
.viewport{
    width:400px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Its child, `.strip`, should expand to contain all of its children as a horizontal row. In the past, to ensure `.strip` could contain its children without clearing, I would either:

- sum up the widths of a pre-determined number of children and hardcode it
- sum of the widths of an unknown number of children via javascript

Since I'm targeting modern browsers, I thought maybe the problem could be solved with using `flexbox`:

```
.strip{
    display: flex;
    height:100px;
}

.item{
    width:150px;
    flex-basis:150px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

It gets tantalizingly close, but all my `item`s are stacked on top of one another:

http://jsfiddle.net/rytPP/14/

Is there someway to space them out, or is there no way to get around `.viewport`'s width constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using `display:inline-block;` for the `.item` and `white-space:nowrap;` for the `.strip`?

```
.strip{
    height:100px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
}

.item{
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

As per this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rytPP/15/)...

That way you're not restricted to flexbox-supporting browsers.

Comment: that's how I would do it.. just a note: if you need the total length for calculations and what not.. give .strip also 'display:inline-block'.. try it out in your fiddle and see that without it you only get the width of the overflow and not the whole scroll ;]